# Reverse word of full sentence

Tags: c#

I want to print string in reverse format:

Input:  `My name is Archit Patel`

Output: `Patel Archit is name My`.

I've tied the following but it displays as `letaP tihcrA si eman ym`.

```
public static string ReverseString(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You would need to split the string into words and the reverse those instead of reversing the characters:

```
text = String.Join(" ", text.Split(' ').Reverse())
```

In framework 3.5:

```
text = String.Join(" ", text.Split(' ').Reverse().ToArray())
```

In framework 2.0:

```
string[] words = text.Split(' ');
Array.Reverse(words);
text = String.Join(" ", words);
```

Answer (score 7):

*"[please send me the code of this program](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15634162/1)."*

Okay ...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "My name is Archit Patel";

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", text.Split(' ').Reverse()));
    }
}
```

Now: what have you learned?

Also, as [Guffa points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15634201/215042), for versions below .Net 4.0 you'll need to add `.ToArray()` since string.Join doesn't have [the correct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) in those versions.

Answer (score 6):

**Try this without in-built functions**

```
public string ReverseFullSentence(string inputString)
        {
            string output = string.Empty;
            string[] splitStrings = inputString.Split(' ');
            for (int i = splitStrings.Length-1; i > -1 ; i--)
            {
                output = output + splitStrings[i]+ " ";
            }
                return output;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do your job! OUTPUT: "Patel Archit is name My".

```
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        string sentence = "My name is Archit Patel";  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        string[] split = sentence.Split(' ');  
        for (int i = split.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)  
        {  
            sb.Append(split[i]);  
            sb.Append(" ");  
        }  
        Console.WriteLine(sb);  
        Console.ReadLine();  
    }
```

Comment: But with this code an extra space ' ' will be added at the end of sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate Rob Anderson answer, but it will reverse complete sentence,
Just editing that

```
string s = "My name is Archit Patel";

        string[] words = s.Split(' ');
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = words.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sb.Append(words[i]);
            sb.Append(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

O/P will be "Patel Archit is name My"

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
string[] words = "My name is Archit Patel".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
IEnumerable<string> reverseWords = words.Reverse();
string reverseSentence = String.Join(" ", reverseWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here is an easy way

```html
        public static string MethodExercise14Logic(string str)
        {
            string[] sentenceWords = str.Split(' ');
            Array.Reverse(sentenceWords);
            string newSentence = string.Join(" ", sentenceWords);
            return newSentence;
        }
```

1. You first create an array called sentence word and use the split method to populate the array with all your words. Note that space is used as a delimiter, telling the split method when exactly to split.
2. You then use the Reverse method in the Array class to reverse the complete array.
3. You then use the Join method of the string class to join your now reversed array into a string called newSentence.
4. Finally the method then returns the newSentence string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stack for solving such queries:

```
String input = "My name is Archit Patel";

        Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>(); 

        for(String word : input.split(" "))
            st.push(word); 

        Iterator it = st.iterator(); 

        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(st.pop()+" ");
        }
```

```
Output String: "Patel Archit is name My"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the split method to put it in an array

```
 string[] words = s.Split(' ');
```

Then reverse the array with array.reverse

```
words = Array.Reverse(words);
```

Now you can print it with a for-each loop and add spaces

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**this.lblStringReverse.Text = Reverse(this.txtString.Text);**

```
private int NoOfWhiteSpaces(string s)
        {
            char[] sArray = s.ToArray<char>();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < (sArray.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (sArray[i] == ' ') count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
        private string Reverse(string s)
        {
            char[] sArray = s.ToArray<char>();
            int startIndex = 0, lastIndex = 0;
            string[] stringArray = new string[NoOfWhiteSpaces(s) + 1];
            int stringIndex = 0, whiteSpaceCount = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < sArray.Length; x++)
            {
                if (sArray[x] == ' ' || whiteSpaceCount == NoOfWhiteSpaces(s))
                {
                    if (whiteSpaceCount == NoOfWhiteSpaces(s))
                    {
                        lastIndex = sArray.Length ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lastIndex = x + 1;
                    }
                    whiteSpaceCount++;

                    char[] sWordArray = new char[lastIndex - startIndex];
                    int j = 0;
                    for (int i = startIndex; i < lastIndex; i++)
                    {
                        sWordArray[j] = sArray[i];
                        j++;
                    }

                    stringArray[stringIndex] = new string(sWordArray);
                    stringIndex++;
                    startIndex = x+1;
                }

            }
            string result = "";
            for (int y = stringArray.Length - 1; y > -1; y--)

                {
                    if (result == "")
                    {

                        result = stringArray[y];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = result + ' ' + stringArray[y];
                    }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string reversewordsInsentence(string sentence)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        string word = string.Empty;
        foreach(char c in sentence)
        {
            if (c == ' ')
            {
                output = word + ' ' + output;
                word = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                word = word + c;
            }
        }
        output = word + ' ' + output;
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want non-linq solution:

```
static string ReverseIntact(char[] input)
{
    //char[] input = "dog world car life".ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length / 2; i++)
    {//reverse the expression
        char tmp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[input.Length - i - 1];
        input[input.Length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
    for (int j = 0, start = 0, end = 0; j <= input.Length; j++)
    {
        if (j == input.Length || input[j] == ' ')
        {
            end = j - 1;
            for (; start < end; )
            {
                char tmp = input[start];
                input[start] = input[end];
                input[end] = tmp;
                start++;
                end--;
            }
            start = j + 1;
        }
    }
    return new string(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Reverse_the_string
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           // string text = "my name is bharath";
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] words = text.Split(' ');
            int k = words.Length - 1;
            for (int i = k;i >= 0;i--)
            {
                Console.Write(words[i] + " " );

            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to an interview question if you need to do it in place. I use one more character for the swap. I assume space is only used as a separator.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcd efg hijk");
        Reverse(sb, 0 , sb.Length - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
        ReverseWords(sb);
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
        ReverseWordOrder(sb);
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
    static void Reverse(StringBuilder sb, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {

        for(int i = startIndex; i <= (endIndex - startIndex) / 2 + startIndex; i++)
        {
            Swap(sb,i, endIndex + startIndex - i);
        }
    }

    private static void Swap(StringBuilder sb, int index1, int index2)
    {
        char temp = sb[index1];
        sb[index1] = sb[index2];
        sb[index2] = temp;
    }

    static void ReverseWords(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= sb.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == sb.Length || sb[i] == ' ')
            {
                Reverse(sb, startIndex, i - 1);
                startIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    static void ReverseWordOrder(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        Reverse(sb, 0, sb.Length - 1);
        ReverseWords(sb);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetReversedWords(string sentence)
        {
            try
            {
                var wordCollection = sentence.Trim().Split(' ');
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var word in wordCollection)
                {
                    var wordAsCharArray = word.ToCharArray();
                    Array.Reverse(wordAsCharArray);
                    builder.Append($"{new string(wordAsCharArray)} ");
                }

                return builder.ToString().Trim();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This Method will reverse word-of-full-sentence without using built-in methods.
public void revSent()
        {
            string s = "My name is Archit Patel";
            List<string> Words = new List<string>(s.Split(' '));
            List<string> Rev = new List<string>();
            for(int i=Words.Count-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                Rev.Add(Words.ElementAt(i));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", Rev));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        //1. Split String at space ' '
        var strDelimitedArray=s.Split(' ');
        /*2. Reverse the sequence of the new generated array i.e from 12345
        [My name is Archit Patel] to 54321 [Patel Archit is name My] and then join it to Form a String 
        from array of strings */
        var strReverseArray = strDelimitedArray.Reverse().Select(str => (new String(str.ToArray())));
        //3. Formulate the new string with spaces
        var strReverse= strReverseArray.Aggregate((x, y) => x + " " + y);
        return strReverse;
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
       string[] strArar = str.Split(" ");
        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();            
        for(int j= strArar.Length-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            strb.Append(strArar[j]);
            strb.Append(" ");
        }

        strb.ToString()
```

Comment: This is more or less just a repeat of some of the existing answers, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28951465) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56376783) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43160063)

Answer (score -2):

```
        string s = "this is a test";

        string[] words = s.Split(' ');
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = words.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = words[i].Length -1; j >= 0;j--)
            {
                sb.Append(words[i][j]);
            }
            sb.Append(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Please elaborate what this piece of code will do, have a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "the quick brown fox";
            string[] arr = str.Split(' ');
            for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
            }


            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Nothing new here. This is similar to many other answers.