# Reverse word of full sentence using for loop in c#

Tags: c#

I want to print the string in reverse format in for loop:

Input:  I'm Learning c#

Output: c# Learning I'm

No Split functions and reverse functions should be used, it has to do only with forloop.

```
for (int i = m.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    b[j]=a[i];
    j++;
    if(a[i]==' '|| a[i]==0)
    {
       for (int x = b.Length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
       {
           c[k] = b[x];
           Console.Write(c[k]);
           k++;
       }
    }

} Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse word of full sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634162/reverse-word-of-full-sentence)

Comment: Did you debug the code? What did you find out?

Comment: I'm getting the output as "c# " alone but not "c# Learning I'm" with the above code

Comment: Off topic: please use better identifiers for your variables. See [Microsoft's C# Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) page for some simple guidelines to follow for identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without split and reverse, I modify your logic little bit to achieve what you need

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          var m="this is mystring";

          var b = new char [m.Length];


          var j=0;
            //Your code goes here
          for (int i = m.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          {
              b[j]=m[i];
              j++;
              if(m[i]==' ' || i==0)
             {
                if(i==0)
                {
                   b[j]=' ';
                }
                for (int x = b.Length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
               {

                   Console.Write(b[x]);

              }
              b=new char[m.Length];
              j=0;
           }

        } 
          Console.ReadKey();
           Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**: "this is mystring"

**Output**: "mystring is this"

Answer (score 5):

You have to create an array of the words in the sentence:

```
var words = input.Split(' ');
```

Then you just loop through the above array from the end to the start:

```
for(int i=words.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    Console.Write(words[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: With this code your output is : c#LearningI'm. You don't have any space between your words. If you change your code to Console.Write(words[i]+" ") you get the correct output.

Comment: @SlavenHvar thanks for your comment. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

With LINQ and string methods you can simplify it:

```
var reversedWords = input.Split().Reverse(); // Split without parameters will use space, tab and new-line characters as delimiter
string output = string.Join(" ", reversedWords); // build reversed words, space is delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use `Stack<Queue<char>>`

Hey if you want to show off your knowledge of data structures, use a queue and a stack! This makes for a very concise answer as well.

You want the sentence to be LIFO with respect to words but FIFO with respect to letters within words, so you need a stack (which are LIFO) of queues (which are FIFO). You can take advantage of the fact that a `string`, a `queue<char>`, and a `stack<char>` all expose `IEnumerable<char>` as well, so it's easy to convert back and forth; once you have all the characters ordered in your data structure, you can extract the whole thing as a character array using `SelectMany()`, which you can pass to a string constructor for the final answer.

This solution uses no `Split()` or `Reverse()` functions, as required.

```
public static string ReverseSentence(string input)
{
    var word = new Queue<char>();
    var sentence = new Stack<IEnumerable<char>>( new [] { word } );
    foreach ( char c in input )
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            sentence.Push( " " );              
            sentence.Push( word = new Queue<char>() ); 
        }
        else
        {
            word.Enqueue(c);
        }
    }
    return new string( sentence.SelectMany( w => w ).ToArray() );
}
```

Usage:

```
public void Test()
{
    var input = "I'm Learning c#";
    var output = ReverseSentence(input);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Output:

```
c# Learning I'm
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V5LUGD)

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a simple console application for your question

Without using `Reverse` and `Split` methods (just `for` loop)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "I'm learning C#";
        string[] result = new string[3];

        int arrayIndex = 0;
        string tempStr = "";

        // Split string 
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            tempStr += input[i].ToString();   
            if (input[i] != ' ')
            {
                result[arrayIndex] = tempStr;
            }
            else
            {
                tempStr = "";
                arrayIndex++;
            }
        }

        // Display Result
        for (int i = result.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.Console.Write(result[i] + ' ');
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Press `Ctrl + F5` to run the program

### Output: C# learning I'm

Comment: .could you please try the answer without using Reverse and Split methods.